# How to complete parenthesis of a function and tab over parameters (if there are any) using Dart Code extension?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm using [Dart Code](https://dartcode.org/) extension on VS Code while working on Flutter projects. I'm unable to add parenthesis and tab over parameters of a function on autocomplete.

Refer to [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29546660/94354428-94accb00-0083-11eb-88e3-95f7c22f2dae.gif) screen recording to see the problem in action.

And [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29546660/94354535-a642a280-0084-11eb-83f5-f0d060928ff0.gif) to see the expected behavior. This is a simple `console.log()` statement that has parenthesis completed after accepting the autocomplete suggestion.

`Insert Argument Placeholder option` is enabled and `enableCompletionCommitCharacters` option is disabled.

VS Code version: 1.49.2

Dart extension version: 3.14.1

Dart/Flutter SDK version: Dart - 2.9.2 / Flutter - 1.20.4

Comment: how can you have pixel noise in a screen capture gif. For some reason I'm looking at mega zoomed version of the gif on a 4K monitor.

Comment: most likely the Javascript completion provider also calls for the insertion of a snippet created on the fly with `insertSnippet` command

Comment: @rioV8 Do you mean that you can see pixels clearly? I guess it's because of the resolution of my monitor which is 1080p.

Comment: for some reason the browser was viewing a gif at 500% zoom, viewing it at 100% it still is a font the for visually impaired.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality was initially missing from the LSP implementation (I presume you have `dart.previewLsp` enabled), though has recently been implemented (as a new setting `dart.completeFunctionCalls` that will supersede the original settings you mentioned):

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2823

You'll need an updated SDK to get this though (though it hasn't currently made a stable SDK, so it may only be on master/dev channels).

Comment: It works. If we change lsp setting we have to restart the IDE to work.